# Why does GNU Indent collapse one level of indentation?

Tags: c, indentation

When I try to format my C code using [GNU Indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/), it doesn't seem to deal with multiple levels of nested indentation. Specifically, it seems to collapse the second level of indentation.

For example, if this is the code I start with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;

    if (argc > 1) {
        printf("# of args: %d\n", argc);
    }

    for (n = 1; n <= 15; n++) {
        if (n % 3 == 0) {
            printf("fizz %d\n", n);
        } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
            printf("buzz %d\n", n);
        } else if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) {
            printf("fizzbuzz %d\n", n);
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I run `indent -kr fizzbuzz.c`, I get this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;

    if (argc > 1) {
    printf("# of args: %d\n", argc);
    }

    for (n = 1; n <= 15; n++) {
    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        printf("fizz %d\n", n);
    } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
        printf("buzz %d\n", n);
    } else if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) {
        printf("fizzbuzz %d\n", n);
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And if I run it with just the defaults (`indent fizzbuzz.c`), I get this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n;

  if (argc > 1)
    {
      printf ("# of args: %d\n", argc);
    }

  for (n = 1; n <= 15; n++)
    {
      if (n % 3 == 0)
    {
      printf ("fizz %d\n", n);
    }
      else if (n % 5 == 0)
    {
      printf ("buzz %d\n", n);
    }
      else if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)
    {
      printf ("fizzbuzz %d\n", n);
    }
      else
    {
      printf ("%d\n", n);
    }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Seems like if it does this out-of-the-box, lots of people would be asking about it, because if it's not a bug, it seems like a really strange way to format your code. Why does it do this?

I'm using version 2.2.11 of GNU Indent.

Comment: does `-kr --no-tabs` fix the problem? if so it's probably tabs displaying the same as four spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses mixed spaces and (8-space) tabs to indent with. You can see that with this minimal example:

```
int main() {
    if (true) {
        while (false) {
            puts("");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run that through `indent -kr` and then `hexdump -C`, I get this:

```
$ indent -kr < mini.c |hexdump -C
00000000  69 6e 74 20 6d 61 69 6e  28 29 0a 7b 0a 20 20 20  |int main().{.   |
00000010  20 69 66 20 28 74 72 75  65 29 20 7b 0a 09 77 68  | if (true) {..wh|
00000020  69 6c 65 20 28 66 61 6c  73 65 29 20 7b 0a 09 20  |ile (false) {.. |
00000030  20 20 20 70 75 74 73 28  22 22 29 3b 0a 09 7d 0a  |   puts("");..}.|
00000040  20 20 20 20 7d 0a 7d 0a                           |    }.}.|
00000048
```

You can see that the `while` is preceded by a single `09` (horizontal tab) byte, while `puts` is preceded by a tab and four spaces (`20`). The default is similar:

```
00000000  69 6e 74 0a 6d 61 69 6e  20 28 29 0a 7b 0a 20 20  |int.main ().{.  |
00000010  69 66 20 28 74 72 75 65  29 0a 20 20 20 20 7b 0a  |if (true).    {.|
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 77 68  69 6c 65 20 28 66 61 6c  |      while (fal|
00000030  73 65 29 0a 09 7b 0a 09  20 20 70 75 74 73 20 28  |se)..{..  puts (|
00000040  22 22 29 3b 0a 09 7d 0a  20 20 20 20 7d 0a 7d 0a  |"");..}.    }.}.|
00000050
```

though here, only the innermost braces and `puts` get a tab.

You can use the `-nut`/`--no-tabs` option to use spaces everywhere:

```
$ indent -kr -nut fizzbuzz.c
```

Alternatively, you can configure your editor and/or terminal to use 8-wide tabs instead of 4 if sticking with the original indentation is important. The `expand` command may help to convert existing files you don't want to re-indent.

Comment: Switched to `indent -kr --no-tabs`, and that doesn't exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you feel like `-nut`. Sometimes you don't. :)